# $C^0([0,1])$ is separable – or isn‘t it?

Tags: functional-analysis, fake-proofs

Using Bernstein polynoms it can be proven that $(X, \|\cdot\|) := (C^0([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_{C^0([0,1])})$ is a seperable vector space.

However, here is my “proof” that this space is not seperable:

Take an arbitrary series $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$. Let $f$ be a function in $X$ with

$$
f(x) = f_n(x) + 1 \qquad \text{for $x \in \left[\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n}\right] =: M_n$}.
$$

(The existence of such a function can be easily seen.)

Then one has
$$
    \|f_n - f\|_X
\ge \|f_n - f\|_{C^0(M_n)}
=   1
\not\rightarrow 0
\qquad \text{for $n \rightarrow \infty$}
$$
ie. $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not a dense subset of $X$. As the series was chosen arbitrarily, $X$ is not seperable.

Where is the flaw in this “proof”?

Comment: Your $f$ isn't continuous in general.

Comment: I did not define $f$ in $(\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n-1})$ and there I can “connect” my $f$?

Comment: What happens at $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, I see your point! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice idea. I mean, it does not work (continuity at $0$ is a problem), but I like the approach.

Comment: @5xum: It works in $L^\infty((0,1))$ (which is not seperable), and I was curious why it does not work here.